# Key/Value Pairs with Multiple Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, key-value

I've been trying to wrap my head around key/value pairs with mutiple values.
What I'm trying to do is iterate through a list in a div, get the values from the `LI`s and then create a key based on the div that they're in, then append those `LI`s to another div with their key as a header. I'm getting a basic result, but my code is producing only one result: one one value for each key. I want to produce multiple values for each key.

What I want to end up with is an object like this, but I don't know how to produce that dynamically with the data I've got:

```
{ "bands": [
    { "band": "beatles", "musician": "john" },
    { "band": "beatles", "musician": "paul" },
    { "band": "beatles", "musician": "ringo" },
    { "band": "beatles", "musician": "george" },
    { "band": "stones", "musician": "mick" },
    { "band": "stones", "musician": "keith" },
    { "band": "stones", "musician": "ronnie" },
    { "band": "stones", "musician": "charlie" },

] }
```

HTML

```
<button>Click 'em</button>
<div id="beatles">
  <ul>
    <li>John</li>
    <li>Paul</li>
    <li>Ringo</li>
    <li>George</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="stones">
  <ul>
    <li>Mick</li>
    <li>Keith</li>
    <li>Ronnie</li>
    <li>Charlie</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="beatlesList">
  <ul></ul>
</div>
<div id="stonesList">
  <ul></ul>
</div>
```

JS/JQ

```
$('button').click(function(){
    var $bands = {}
  $('ul li').each(function(){
    var $bandName = $(this).parents('div').attr('id');
    var $bandMember = $(this).text();
    console.log($bandName);
    $bands[$bandName] = $bandMember;
  })
  console.log($bands);
  $.each($bands,function(k,v){
    if(k === "beatles") {
        $('#beatlesList').prepend('<h2>' + k + '</h2>')
        $('#beatlesList ul').append('<li>' + v + '</li>')
    } else {
        $('#stonesList').prepend('<h2>' + k + '</h2>')
        $('#stonesList ul').append('<li>' + v + '</li>')
    }
  })
})
```

Expected HTML Outcome

```
<button>Click 'em</button>
<div id="beatles">
  <ul>
    <li>John</li>
    <li>Paul</li>
    <li>Ringo</li>
    <li>George</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="stones">
  <ul>
    <li>Mick</li>
    <li>Keith</li>
    <li>Ronnie</li>
    <li>Charlie</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="beatlesList">
<h2>beatles</h2>
  <ul>
<li>John</li>
<li>Paul</li>
<li>Ringo</li>
<li>George</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div id="stonesList">
<h2>stones</h2>
  <ul>
<li>Mick</li>
<li>Keith</li>
<li>Ronnie</li>
<li>Charlie</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pixelsmith/nsz2n7zk/)

Comment: So you are moving a list to another div. Why don't you move the whole list over and add the key as a title rather than looping over the list?

Comment: I don't want to move the list, I want to create one dynamically from various elements based on certain requirements (presence of a certain class). The example above is a simplified case.

Comment: Please show the expected output for your HTML from that input.

Comment: Does the JSON you posted get used at all?  It looks like you might just want to move the entire UL from one spot to a second.  Is that right?

Comment: Please see the previous comment. This is a simplified case.

Comment: This is a confusing question: *"What I want to end up with is an object like this"* and *"Expected HTML Outcome"*...  JSON is not HTML.

Answer (score 1):

This code will create the object you wanted

```
var $bands = {'bands':[]};
  $('ul li').each(function(){
    var $bandName = $(this).parents('div').attr('id');
    var $bandMember = $(this).text();
    console.log($bandName);

    $bands['bands'].push({'band':$bandName,'musician':$bandMember});
  })
```

and this is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nsz2n7zk/3/)

you can loop now over the object and create the list you wanted.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

I am not clear as to why you need to do this. But the below approach will work for you.

What you want to do is to create an object which has a single object **bands** which should in turn hold an array of objects. So, you need to build up the array of objects which contain the **band** and **musician** properties.

```
var $bands = {}
$bands.bands = [];
$('ul li').each(function(){
  var $bandName = $(this).parents('div').attr('id');
  var $bandMember = $(this).text();
  $bands.bands.push({band: $bandName, musician: $bandMember});
});
console.log($bands.bands);
```

Now `$bands.bands` holds an array of objects and you can loop over them using `forEach`.

```
$bands.bands.forEach(function(object){
if(object.band === "beatles") {
    //$('#beatlesList').prepend('<h2>' + object.band + '</h2>')
    $('#beatlesList ul').append('<li>' + object.musician + '</li>')
} else {
    //$('#stonesList').prepend('<h2>' +object.band+ '</h2>')
    $('#stonesList ul').append('<li>' + object.musician + '</li>')
}
```

});

I commented out the lines which add the heading because you don't want to prepend a heading for every object. Instead you can add it to the html.

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j4wq9crc/2/)

Answer (score 1):

It is not 100% clear in my mind what you are after.  I think this is going to do what you appear to be attempting.  If ultimately you are looking to move items rather than clone and massage them then of course this answer could be simplified.  Of course, I could have your request completely incorrect.  How does the JSON you posted factor into this?  Are you looking for that JSON result, or are you looking for the result HTML you posted, or both?

```js
document.getElementById("go").addEventListener("click", function(){

  var sources = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".sourceData"));
  sources.forEach(function(item){
    var target = document.getElementById(item.id + "List");
    if (!target) { return; }
    
    var targetTitle = item.id
    targetTitle = targetTitle.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + targetTitle.slice(1);
    target.querySelector("h2").innerText = targetTitle;

    var parent = target.querySelector("ul");
    var children = Array.from(item.querySelectorAll("li"));
    children.forEach(function(item){
      var el = document.createElement("li");
      el.innerText = item.innerText;
      parent.appendChild(el);
    });
  });
  
});
```

```css
#beatles, #beatlesList { background-color: aliceblue; }
#stones, #stonesList { background-color: mistyrose; }
```

```html
<div id="beatles" class="sourceData">
  <ul>
    <li>John</li>
    <li>Paul</li>
    <li>Ringo</li>
    <li>George</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="stones" class="sourceData">
  <ul>
    <li>Mick</li>
    <li>Keith</li>
    <li>Ronnie</li>
    <li>Charlie</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="beatlesList">
  <h2></h2>
  <ul></ul>
</div>

<div id="stonesList">
  <h2></h2>
  <ul></ul>
</div>

<button id="go">Go</button>
```

Comment: I like that you do this with plain JavaScript.

Comment: I'm only using JSON because it seemed to match my need. I simply need to create an object where I can have multiple values in the same keys. I'm looking for the HTML result; I'm agnostic about how I get there.

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't be building your data from html, you should be building your html from your data.

However since you probably have a need for this for some reason or another, A dictionary is a key value set.  so if you have two or more values with the same key the last one written will overwrite the prior. You should set up each object as an array of values

```
$('button').click(function(){
    var $bands = {};
    $('ul li').each(function(){
        var $bandName = $(this).parents('div').attr('id');
        var $bandMember = $(this).text();
        console.log($bandName);

        //if the key doesn't exist create it as an array
        if($bands[$bandName] == undefined)
            $bands[$bandName] = [];
        //add value to array
        $bands[$bandName].push( $bandMember);
    })
    console.log($bands);
    $.each($bands,function(k,v){
        //using k which could be dynamic you could even create the whole thing being dynamic appending new div tags to the body element if they do not exist
        if(k === "beatles") {
            $('#beatlesList').prepend('<h2>' + k + '</h2>');
            //iterate through each value in array
            for(var i = 0; i < v.length;i++) {
                $('#beatlesList ul').append('<li>' + v[i] + '</li>');
            }       
        } else {
            $('#stonesList').prepend('<h2>' + k + '</h2>');
            for(var i = 0; i < v.length;i++) {
                $('#stonesList ul').append('<li>' + v[i] + '</li>');
            }
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I realize now that I'm misusing the JSON, which I didn't before.

I don't need JSON, it's just the tool I latched onto as it seemed to fit my need. I just need a tool that does something what I've described above.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var parameters = new[] {
            new KeyValuePair<string, object?>("@param1", obj.param1),
            new KeyValuePair<string, object?>("@param2", obj.param2),
            new KeyValuePair<string, object?>("@param3", obj.param3),
            new KeyValuePair<string, object?>("@param4", obj.param4)
        }
```